Emulate closing form with X in VB.NET
Is there a way other than SendKeys to emulate the manual closing of a form?
I need to emulate a closure of the form AS "natural" as possible, meaning I would need to literally (if possible) send an instruction which emulates specifically the top-right X button to close the form. SendKeys is not an option as it seems it skips the FormClosing event, which I need to trigger.

It's as simple as Me.Close().

... where the Me. part can almost always be dropped.

Sounds like an x/y problem. What are specifically trying to accomplish through this?

it's hard to explain since it's a huge program. but I saw closing normally a form is good, using the toolbar instead generates a visual bug which i'm trying to avoid.

using the toolbar instead generates a visual bug  What's the visual bug?

in fact the problem in this program was a certain trail of methods and events which led to a graphic bug because a Dispose() was called twice, from inside and outside the form during the closure, so basically handling those events with Me.Close() and removing one Dispose() solved the issue.

@grimoiredark - You should have posted all of the code to reproduce the bug. You did indeed ask us an X-Y problem.

I can't post the code, there are multiple files and much code involved. My problem was simple as that, a way to emulate closing the form.

@grimoiredark - The phrase "emulate closing the form" doesn't even really make sense. Nonetheless, it's really a code issue and you don't seem to be willing to post the code. It's why this question has remained unanswered.

As I said, you can't  think of posting the code, if I could I would have done it.

@grimoiredark - Given the description of the problem you could have posted very simple code. But given your solution the description doesn't match. You would have had to replicate your issue and doing that would have helped you solve your own problem. You'll be a better coder if you could learn how to do that.

No, you're assuming too much. My take and need was only: I have to emulate closing the form. The rest is futile. Still I don't know why you complain, you already gave a solution.

@grimoiredark - I complain because the primary purpose of this site is to create a repository of quality questions and answers for future readers. It's only secondary that the OP gets an answer. So I am trying to encourage you to ask a good question so that future readers get good value.

As suggested in the comments, the easiest way is using Me.Close() although in my case it wasn't a straight take. Still it worked fine after a couple of changes in the code.
